# Playwright not getting full html page

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-asyncio, playwright

```py
import asyncio

from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser


async def get_book_html(id: int) -> HTMLParser:
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        url = f'https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/{id}'
        await page.goto(url, timeout=120000)
        html = HTMLParser(await page.content())
        with open('testing/book.html', 'w') as f:
            f.write(await page.content())
        await browser.close()
        return html


async def run() -> None:
    html = await get_book_html(5)
    print(html.css_first('title').text())


asyncio.run(run())
```

I'm trying to get data from this page: `https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/5`

The html returned it's a mess: `https://ctxt.io/2/AACwEGE2EA` it looks like the page isn't fully loaded or anything like that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're writing the page content to a file, which is exactly what you're getting... The raw html. You'd need to grab all the other files or take a screenshot

Comment: the raw html shouldnt keep the tags that i see using inspect in browser?

Comment: Why do you want the whole HTML? Usually, in web scraping you want particular pieces of data from the HTML. This is a single page app, and content is added dynamically after load by JS, so it's not clear that you're waiting long enough for whatever data you want (please specify expected output) might be. It's also unusal to be using `selectolax.parser` when Playwright already has access to the actual page and a full suite of native parsers. It's a [common antipattern](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#using-a-separate-html-parser-with-puppeteer) I've written about in Puppeteer.

Comment: Also, many pages restrict crawlers and provide truncated HTML if you're detected as a robot.

Comment: I would like to get full html file of 12k books, save into S3, then use lambdas to extract the content of html and insert into pgsql database.

Comment: It's a learning project but i'm struggling to get the content inside html. How can i wait till the full page is loaded to get all data @ggorlen?

Comment: Generally, extract the data you want up front rather than saving the HTML first and trying to get it later. In most cases, you need the live page to inject the content with JS. As far as waiting for the page to completely load, [see the docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations#when-is-the-page-loaded). In short, it's use case specific. Identify the data you want, then wait for it to be there with [locators](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators), and use Playwright to do whatever actions need to be done to make it show up. If you provide the expected output, I can show you how to get it.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of (this issue)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77936414/not-all-elements-of-the-page-appear-in-chromium-with-playwright/77961933#77961933]