# Not all elements of the page appear in Chromium with Playwright

Tags: python, pytest, chromium, playwright

I am learning to write automated tests in Python using pytest and Playwright. The issue I'm facing is that when I run a test on a specific website, not all elements on that page appear - usually, it's a message about cookies and a few links in the footer. When I run the regular Chrome browser, all these elements are present on the page. It's not a code issue because the same code works without any problems on another laptop (the other laptop has the exact same library versions and Python, is in the same network, and uses the same operating system). I've tried reinstalling Python, PyCharm, pytest, Playwright, Google Chrome browser, but it didn't solve the issue. I also installed Node.js and tried to force the same browser version for Playwright. The problem occurs on all websites. I have no idea what could be causing this.

Comment: Please share a complete, runnable [mcve] including your code and the site you're automating. Without that, there's no way to really guess. One of many things can cause the issue, but generally try running headfully or setting a user agent and waiting for the elements to appear if it's a single page app. Also, iframes may be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and it seems on a lot of pages cookies can get loaded in stages, so you have to keep looking for them with context.cookies() while the page is loading. If you don't look for them, the page just appears to hang, partially loaded.

I have a load_page() function in my code that checks for cookies using a get_cookies() function. I've included the get_cookies() function below and you need a while loop to continue while it returns a non-zero value. I also add the get_cookies() function to the requestfinished and requestfailed events that I set up when I create the browser context.

```
context.on('requestfinished', lambda r: get_cookies(context))
context.on('requestfailed', lambda r: get_cookies(context))
```

```
def get_cookies(context):
    """
    Checks for new cookies. This function running is critical to QlikView pages loading 
    properly, or else the pages will look like they are only partially loading.
    """
    global cookies
    cookie_set = {tempdict['name'] for tempdict in cookies}
    new_cookies = context.cookies()
    context_cookie_set = {tempdict['name'] for tempdict in new_cookies}
    new_cookie_set = context_cookie_set - cookie_set
    if len(new_cookie_set) == 0:
        #print('No new cookies at this time')
        return 0
    else:
        pass
    
    cookies = new_cookies
    return len(new_cookie_set)
```

There's probably a nicer way of doing this, but it works for me.

Hope that helps.